# Apply css class to column when export to excel in Ag-Grid

Tags: vue.js, export-to-excel, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am trying to change content of column while exporting to excel from ag-grid but export to excel is remove the old styling like css class for that column. like

I have 3 column in my grid: 1) name 2)address 3)phone

- name: Test
- address: New York
- phone: 000-000-00

I have applied a css classname to address which will change background color based on value
like

- red-class to New York
- green-class to Kansas

now I want to change the content of address column like, it will display information with Street, Flat Number, and many other. so I am changing that content from **processCellCallback()** and now it has complete value **(like 47 W 13th St, New York, NY 10011, USA)**

```
processCellCallback: function(cell) {
          if(cell.column.colId == 'address') {
            return '47 W 13th St ' + cell.value + ' NY 10011, USA';
          } else {
            return cell.value;
          }
        }
```

but however I can see that data are displaying in color combination in grid but not in downloaded excel file.

I can check that **renderer** for that column is also applied in grid but not applied in excel file.
but the same thing is work with **Phone** column because it was unchanged, so the css style is applied in downloaded excel file.

so anyone knows why this is happening, thanks in advance.

for information:
using ag-grid in vue.js

Answer (score 0):

Check out the property "excelStyles" on the ag-grid properties. This will need to be set as well:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/#renderingStyling